# check if all elements of an array exists in a table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, intersection

I have `courses` and `student_courses` table. If a student completed a course I'm inserting a row in `student_courses` table with `student_id` and `course_id`. Now I have a scenario where I need to get all `student_ids` from `student_courses` table if a student completed certain numbers of courses. I am getting `course_ids` from another query as an array. Is there any way to make this query efficiently in laravel, because there is already 100k+ data in `student_courses` table?

Comment: What have you tried? Also please post your models with the relationships

Comment: This broad requirements dump contains no code and no sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know using query, but you can do that using array_intersect() function.

```
// get all courses id you want to check into one array
$checkCourses = [1,2,...];

// get all courses completed by student
$completedCourses = StudentCourse::where('student_id', $studentId)->pluck('course_id');
```

now you can use array_intersect()

```
$result = array_intersect($completedCourses, $checkCourses);
if(!empty($result)) {
    // your code...
}
```

following query will gives the student who completed course id (1,3,4)

```
DB::query("SELECT student_id FROM student_courses WHERE course_id IN (1,3,4) GROUP BY student_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3");
```

where count 3 is size of total course you want to check, in above query we are checking with course id 1,3,4 so HAVING COUNT(*) is 3

Comment: Thanks for your time, But how would i get student ids, when my requirement is to get those.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed I added query, please check and update as per your requirenment.

Comment: I will check the result and let you know,. Thanks again.